# Unity3D, как работает The Fisher-Yates Shuffle? (на рус. Тасование Фишера-Йетса)

Tags: unity3d, числа

С места в карьер, вопрос с кодом: [The Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0), (на рус. "Тасование Фишера-Йетса", или "Тасование Кнута") как он создаёт случайные значения на Unity3D, языке C#, я не очень понимаю. Буду очень признателен, если кто знает. Заранее спасибо! :)

(Нашёл его в [видео уроке по созданию TDS игры](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7BL-lboRXo) (видео на англ. языке))

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Utility
{
    public static T[] ShuffleArray<T>(T[] array, int seed)
    {   //             ↓pRandomNumberGenerator
        System.Random prng = new System.Random(seed);

        for (int i =0; i <array.Length -1; i++)
        {
            int randomIndex = prng.Next(i, array.Length);
            T tempItem = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = array[i];
            array[i] = tempItem;
        }

    return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: класс `System.Random` генерирует псевдо случайные значения, когда Вы вызываете у него метод `Next()`

Comment: `Random.Range(min, max)` из `UnityEngine`.